# how can I read old varnish logs?

Tags: logging, varnish

In `/var/log/varnish/` I have some old varnish logs, produced by `varnishlog` which, due to `logrotated`, are now in gz format:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 143068514 Aug 10 23:59 varnish.log.2017-08-10.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 156373518 Aug 11 23:59 varnish.log.2017-08-11.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 134255825 Aug 12 23:59 varnish.log.2017-08-12.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 156992529 Aug 13 23:59 varnish.log.2017-08-13.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 176751837 Aug 14 23:59 varnish.log.2017-08-14.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 155948012 Aug 16 00:01 varnish.log.2017-08-15.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 varnishlog varnish 169977134 Aug 17 00:01 varnish.log.2017-08-16.gz
```

I've extracted those in another location and tried to view them via `head`/`more` but they look binary.

So I then tried opening them with `varnishlog` using either of the following parameters:

```
[-N filename]             VSM filename
[-r filename]             Binary file input
```

But that didn't work giving me:

```
Can't open log - retrying for 5 seconds
```

and:

```
Can't open log file (Not a VSL file:
```

Any idea on how can I inspect those historical logs from varnish?

p.s I use `varnish-4.1.1`

Comment: Are these log files produced with varnishncsa? http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2011/05/configure-varnish-logs-varnishnsca-logrotate-and-awstats-1014/

Comment: @bgtvfr: No. `varnishncsa` produces ncsa log format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format which is human readable, and by looking at `ps -axu` I see that it's `varnishlog` that produces those logs in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way was indeed using `-r` but my files were corrupted due to an improper way of rotating them in a customized `/etc/logrotate.d/varnish`. Reverting to the default rotate method worked.

Answer (score 3):

The error you see is due to lack of privileges. Try:

```
sudo varnishlog -N <file.vsm> -d
```

Comment: Whether I do it via `sudo` or as being `root` the result is: `Can't open log - retrying for 5 seconds`. Maybe it's not in the expected format.

Comment: What happen if you try to read the varnishlog file currently being written?  I mean something like: `sudo varnishlog -N /var/lib/varnish/hostname/_.vsm -d`

Comment: Yes, that works, but that file doesn't seem to relate to those large daily archived varnishlog generated files I have in `/var/log/varnish`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the log by unzipping it with

```
gunzip -c <filename.log.gz>
```

Then you can read it with

```
varnishlog -r  <filename.log>
```